# Can Torrent/DHT network remember my IP?

Tags: networking, bittorrent, denial-of-service, peer-to-peer

I suspect that my torrent activity casted some sort of "natural" DDOS attack on me.

I had UPnP configured and each time I was starting `uTorrent` client, it was generating new random port and was operating at this port.

Additionally I have static IP address.

After some time I noticed that my external interface is constantly bombarded with connect attempts from different IPs and different ports.

Can this because torrent nodes were remembering my IP and port for a long time and now trying to connect to me in good will, but in mass DDOSing me?

Is this possible scenario?

Or this can be an effect of DHT network?

Comment: Short answer: You are correct.  Usually the traffic to that IP will die off after you stop torrenting for a while.

Answer (score 0):

If you been active on a torrent and quit, other peers still has you in their peer list. Some of them may be active on the torrent for a very long time.

Also, some bittorrent clients saves a list of other peers that it has been in contact with when it quits. This is done to speed up things when the client is re-started.

The registration on the DHT network needs to be updated every 15 min to be active, so that will time out very fast.